# Cant get this IPCONFIG command to display between <p></p> HTML tags

Tags: html, windows, batch-file, cmd, ipconfig

I am having trouble getting this simple code to display the ip address in between `<p>`/`</p>` HTML tags.

The code below works, outputting to a text file is ok.

```
if /i %opt%==1 ipconfig |findstr "IPv4">>"..\LOGS\%NAME%\%serial% %MAC%".txt
```

The code below is where I would like to embed the CMD code but it just ignores the code or prints in plain text depending on how I modify it; would it need escape characters?

```
^<td width="38%%" class="table-border-left"^>^<p^>IP Address^</p^>^</td^>
```

and output to a HTML file:

```
  >> "..\LOGS\NAME%\%serial% %MAC%".html
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do not use `Set /P` to request user input, use the `choice.exe` command utility so that the end user can only input a known key according to your expectations. Open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to read its syntax and usage information. If you ignore that advice, _which would be foolhardy_, you should at the very least, change `if /i %opt%==1` to `If "%opt:"=%" == "1"` for a little more protection against their potential input strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is essentially, 'How do I obtain just the IPv4 Address from ipconfig.exe, and use it'?

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example using your [ipconfig](/questions/tagged/ipconfig) command, *(the result is returned as `%%J`)*:

```sh
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^[ ][ ]*IPv4[ ]"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%H In ("%%G") Do For /F %%J In ("%%I"
) Do Echo ^<td width="38%%" class="table-border-left"^>^<p^>%%J^</p^>^</td^>
```

The above is a single line command, which has been split to work without modification, but remain readable. If you want to run it as a single line then it would look like this:

```sh
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^[ ][ ]*IPv4[ ]"') Do For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%H In ("%%G") Do For /F %%J In ("%%I") Do Echo ^<td width="38%%" class="table-border-left"^>^<p^>%%J^</p^>^</td^>
```

*Please note that there may be more than one adapter bound to TCP/IP, so you may see more than one result returned*

Comment: Please note, based upon your self-answer, _which does not offer any solution to your asked question_, it suggests that you are trying to return the results of multiple commands in a single HTML format. For that reason, I would strongly advise that you do not try to do all of this using batch language, and instead use PowerShell, which can return all of your output already in the format you need.

Comment: So what I noticed was a reply asking for the full HTML line of code as i only posted a snippet off it, So I replied with the Add Answer to add the code as i presumed you cant add code it in the comments.
In future I will use the comments box.

Comment: Sorry i marked your answer as working just now, ive only posted two posts since joining,

Answer (score 1):

To create valid HTML I'd suggest you use a tool like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), instead of fiddling with Batch (and lots of escape characters).

```
ipconfig | xidel -se "(<td width='38%' class='table-border-left'><p>{extract($raw,'IPv4.+: (.+)',1)}</p></td>)"
```

Alternatively, instead of piping `ipconfig` to `xidel`, you can use [`system()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-system) to call `ipconfig` from within the query. For proper indentation you can use `--output-node-indent`.

```
xidel -se "(<td width='38%' class='table-border-left'><p>{extract(system('ipconfig'),'IPv4.+: (.+)',1)}</p></td>)" --output-node-format=html --output-node-indent
```