# how can I convert wmic memorychip get SMBIOSMemoryType numerical value to name (DDR) and output to a txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I am currently in the process of writing a script to output information gathered from wmic etc to txt file or html file.

I know you can get the memory type ie DDR3, DDR4 etc with the command `wmic memorychip get SMBIOSMemoryType which shows the type in numerical value ie 26 for DDR4.

But is there a batch script that can be written to convert the value to show DDR3/ DDR4 etc and output it to a variable .

20 = DDR

21 = DDR2

22 = DDR2 FB-DIMM

24 = DDR3

26 = DDR4

I cant seem to add code in a comment box so i have updated this below to what i have found out.

This seems to work in principle.

```
for /F "skip=1" %%E in ('
    wmic memorychip get SMBIOSMemoryType
') do for /F %%F in ("%%E") do set "FF=%%F"
if %FF% equ 26 (
    goto ramtype1
    )
if %FF% equ 24 (
    goto ramtype2
    )
if %FF% equ 21 (
    goto ramtype3
) else (
    goto ramtype4
)

:ramtype1
echo DDR4
pause
exit
:ramtype2
echo DDR3
pause
exit
:ramtype3
echo DDR2
pause
exit
:ramtype4
echo other
pause
exit

Pause
```

This code is similar.

```
for /F "skip=1" %%E in ('
    wmic memorychip get SMBIOSMemoryType
') do for /F %%F in ("%%E") do set "FF=%%F"
if %FF% equ 26 (
    echo Ram Type is DDR4.
    if %FF% equ 24 (
    echo Ram Type is DDR4.
)
) else (
    echo Unknown
)
```

Need the above to work with the code below or similar.

if /i %opt%==1 echo !CODE HERE!  >> "..\NCR_STAGING_LOGS\ASDA%STORENAME%%serial% %MAC%".html

Not having much look unfortunately

I would normally have the below to get wmic info and pass it to a %variable% like %Memtype% below but this obvioausly outputs 26 as DDR4.

```
set torun=wmic memorychip get SMBIOSMemoryType
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('%torun%') do set MemType=%%a
```

Comment: You'll have to hard-code the strings in a couple of `if`s…

Comment: Hi thanks do you have an example of this.

Comment: Yeh i have looked, i suppose its hard to explain what i need it to do.
Something like --- if string is this than print this instead else do this

Comment: Thanks @KJ before your comment i had come up with this below but i still need to print it out or echo it in a %string%
    for /F "skip=1" %%E in ('
    wmic memorychip get SMBIOSMemoryType
') do for /F %%F in ("%%E") do set "FF=%%F"
if %FF% equ 26 (
    goto ramtype1
 )
if %FF% equ 24 (
    goto ramtype2
 )
if %FF% equ 21 (
    goto ramtype3
) else (
    goto rantype4
)

:ramtype1
echo DDR4
pause
exit
:ramtype2
echo DDR3
pause
exit
:ramtype3
echo DDR2
pause
exit
:ramtype4
echo other
pause
exit

Pause
</code>

Comment: edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a single line example to be used within a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), and which uses your specified `SMBIOSMemoryType` property, *(which is only available in Windows 10/Server 2016+)*.

```sh
(For %%G In ("1=DDR" "2=DDR2" "4=DDR3" "6=DDR4") Do Set "_2%%~G") & For /F EOL^=S %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe MemoryChip Where "SMBIOSMemoryType='20' Or SMBIOSMemoryType='21' Or SMBIOSMemoryType='24' Or SMBIOSMemoryType='26'" Get SMBIOSMemoryType 2^>NUL') Do For %%I In (%%H) Do For /F %%J ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /D /C "Echo(!_%%I!") Do Echo(%%J
```

*Please also note, that your initial [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) query will output the same number of results as there are installed memory sticks. If you don't want that, you'll have to modify the code yourself as needed, because doing so is beyond the scope of your request to replace the uint32 data type results with their respective strings.*

Comment: Thanks ill give that a try too.

Can you see any way to get the same info from windows prior to windows10 ie windows 7 etc as the command is wmic memorychip get memorytype which displays a 0 for DDR4.

Comment: Not using simple batch files. The only method I can envisage would to be to access and read the SMBIOS table structure directly. Please be very aware however that this relies upon when the SMBIOS was designed and written. If an older PC hasn't updated their BIOS firmware, and therefore didn't know what DDR3 or DDR4 was, then clearly that information will not be available in the table, and cannot therefore be extracted from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution does this look right.

This code seems to work and outputs my ram as DDr4

```
for /F "skip=1" %%E in ('
    wmic memorychip get SMBIOSMemoryType
') do for /F %%F in ("%%E") do set "FF=%%F"
if %FF% equ 26 (
    echo Ram Type is DDR4.)>"myNewTextFile.txt"
if %FF% equ 24 (
    echo Ram Type is DDR3.)>"myNewTextFile.txt"
if %FF% equ 21 (
    echo Ram Type is DDR2.)>"myNewTextFile.txt"

)
)
) else (
    echo Unknown 
)>"myNewTextFile.txt"
```

**[Edit /]**

```
 (
        If %FF% Equ 26 (
            Echo Ram Type is DDR4.
        ) Else If %FF% Equ 24 (
            Echo Ram Type is DDR3.
        ) Else If %FF% Equ 21 (
            Echo Ram Type is DDR2.
        ) Else Echo Unknown
    ) 1>"myNewTextFile.txt"
```

Tried the above and the single line code
but even thru it works it breaks the rest of the code below.

This is what I am using.

```
if /i %opt%==1 for /F "skip=1" %%E in ('
    wmic memorychip get SMBIOSMemoryType
') do for /F %%F in ("%%E") do set "FF=%%F"
(
    If %FF% Equ 26 (
        Echo Ram Type is DDR4.
    ) Else If %FF% Equ 24 (
        Echo Ram Type is DDR3.
    ) Else If %FF% Equ 21 (
        Echo Ram Type is DDR2.
    ) Else Echo Unknown
) 1>"myNewTextFile.txt"
```

In my batch file I have a menu system using
`if /i %opt%==1` thru to `if /i %opt%==10`
and the code above breaks when I select option two from my menu.

**[Edit2 /]**

```
If "%opt:"=%" == "1" (
    For /F "Skip=1" %%E In (
        'WMIC MemoryChip Get SMBIOSMemoryType'
    ) Do For /F %%F In (
        "%%E"
    ) Do Set "FF=%%F"
    (
        If %FF% Equ 26 (
            Echo Ram Type is DDR4.
        ) Else If %FF% Equ 24 (
            Echo Ram Type is DDR3.
        ) Else If %FF% Equ 21 (
            Echo Ram Type is DDR2.
        ) Else Echo Unknown
    ) 1>"myNewTextFile.txt"
)
```

Comment: No it does not look right, your `If/Else` sequence, _(lines `4` to `15` incl)_, should look more like this: `(If %FF% Equ 26 (Echo Ram Type is DDR4.)Else If %FF% Equ 24 (Echo Ram Type is DDR3.)Else If %FF% Equ 21 (Echo Ram Type is DDR2.)Else Echo Unknown)>"myNewTextFile.txt"` I've used a single line to replace it all, because you seem to prefer them.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. 

Comment: You're welcome! If it does work for you, please ensure that you additionally edit the answer above as necessary, _(otherwise it may attract downvotes)_.

Comment: How would i write the above on mutiple lines like the example i posted so i can figure it out, its not just the Else statement but the bracket placement too i guess.

Comment: I have added an **[Edit /]** to your answer, to show the structure over multiple lines for readability and hopefully better understanding. Please test and then adjust your answer as necessary.

Comment: Your original suggestion on one line works beautifully, And thanks for explaining the structure..

Comment: getting abit messy above, do i need to edit the original question you think?

Comment: That is because you have not parenthesized the code for option 1. I have added another edit, **[Edit2 /]**, to your answer. Please note however that this has all gone way beyond your asked question, so please try not to ask for additional help, without starting a new question.

Comment: You should also not use `set /p` for your end user to choose from a pre-determined list. There is a `choice` command utility designed exactly for that. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its syntax and usage information.

Comment: The reason I am using set instead of chcice is that the script was originally written like that and I am just adding and modifying it to update it. Its being used on systems ranging from Windows Xp through to Windows 10. The user would choose options with the number keys

Comment: Well Windows XP does not have the choice.exe utility, so you'll probably need to stick with `set /p`. However, it is very important to note that a `set /p` prompt allows your end user to just press the `[ENTER]` key, therefore submitting nothing, it also allows them to type anything at all, including problematic characters, accidentally or deliberately, and even malicious code. You therefore need to ensure that the input received was only one of the following `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, or `10`, before you do anything else with it. _Rule 1:_ Your end user cannot to be trusted.

Comment: I have now re-written the code to use the CHOICE  LIST now and your Code from your answer works as it should .
The problem was the original script used the below



if /i %opt%==1
if /i %opt%==2
if /i %opt%==3
ETC.
I have to use the SET STORENAME="" and   SET /p STORENAME=Enter Store Name .

To get info from the user

Comment: Well you can clearly see above, that I changed that `if` statement to `If "%opt:"=%" == "1"`, for some additional protection, and I even told you exactly that, in the comments of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225148/cant-get-this-ipconfig-command-to-display-between-p-p-html-tags#comment120581424_68225148). Your `Set`, and `Set /P` syntax above is also not recommended, use `Set "STORENAME="`, then `Set /P "STORENAME=Type your Store Name, and press Enter>"`. Notice the placement of the double-quotes.